# How to force an app to simulate in iPhone simulation using an iPad using Expo?

Tags: macos, react-native, expo

I'm currently using Expo to build an iPhone app.
I'm not supporting iPad and I have it so when it builds on iPad it runs in an iPhone Simulation.

The problem is I can't develop with Expo using this approach.
The app shows up as an iPad app, but this is not the mode being shipped to users.

According to [this](https://forums.expo.io/t/is-there-a-way-to-enable-iphone-mode-on-an-ipad-with-expo/6045/2) I might have some luck adding `ios.supportsTablet` to the app.json file and setting it to `false` but it didn't change anything.

Is there another configuration value I'm missing to force iPhone simulation mode on an iPad?
I'd rather not eject if I don't have to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](https://forums.expo.io/t/solved-failing-ipad-review-for-iphone-only-app-how-can-i-test-in-2x-mode-in-expo/9003), there currently isn't a way to live develop using "iPhone mode" on an iPad.

> *The Expo Client app can’t change its tablet support on the fly,
>   unfortunately, so it will always adapt your project to the iPad
>   viewport.*

So, following the above forum here is how you get around it:

- Run `exp build:ios -t simulator`
- Open Simulator
- Select Hardware/Device/iOs 11.x/iPad x generation
- Unpack the generated build from the first command
- You should have a file named *yourApp.app*
- Drag that file into the iPad you are running in Simulator
- It will install the app on the device and you can then view your creation

This is faster than doing a whole build cycle with TestFlight just to see your changes.
But it still leaves a bit to be desired.